# Restart float numbering with endfloat with labels

Tags: floats, appendices, endfloat

I need to restart figure numbering in the Appendix, so that figures are 1, 2, ..; then S1, S2, .... Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to have endfloat refer to the two groups of figures differently. What I would like to have happen is as in the following code (without endfloat):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
% \usepackage{endfloat}
\begin{document}

As we see in figure \ref{fig1} (and also in supplemental figure \ref{figS1}) \ldots

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{fig1}
  \caption{ One.  } \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{figS1}
  \caption{ Supplement, one.  } \label{figS1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

... but uncommenting endfloat (and deleting temporary files) causes the text and list of figures to refer to S1 and S2 (instead of 1 and S1), and the `[Figure X about here]` to refer to 1 and 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The counter `postfigure` needs to also be reset, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[nofiglist]{endfloat}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\clearpage

\section{Test}
As we see in figure \ref{fig1} (and also in supplemental figure \ref{figS1}) \ldots
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{fig1}
  \caption{ One.  } \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\processdelayedfloats

\clearpage
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thepostfigure}{S\arabic{postfigure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{postfigure}{0}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{figS1}
  \caption{ Supplement, one.  } \label{figS1}
\end{figure}
\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The counter used for the numbering “in place” is called `postfigure`, so also this one should be changed.

Here's a solution that exploits `\appendix`. The instruction for changing the counter representation and resetting the counter is written in the `.fff` file, so it will enter into action when the actual typesetting of figures takes place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto{\appendix}{%
  \renewcommand{\thepostfigure}{S\arabic{postfigure}}%
  \setcounter{postfigure}{0}%
  \efloat@iwrite{fff}{%
    \unexpanded{%
      \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}^^J%
      \setcounter{figure}{0}^^J%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

As we see in figure \ref{fig1} (and also in supplemental figure \ref{figS1}) \ldots

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{fig1}
\caption{One.} \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\clearpage % not necessary, just to make the figure go to the next page
\appendix

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{figS1}
\caption{Supplement, one.} \label{figS1}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\end{document}
```

For producing the picture, the page height has been artificially reduced.

[image]

### UPDATE

Unfortunately, `endfloat` version 2.6 introduced a bug which will make it not work as expected, besides breaking the code above. The package changed `\immediate\write` into `\immediate\protected@write{}`, which is wrong because `\immediate` cannot work in this situation.

Updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% fix the wrong code in endfloat.sty
\@ifundefined{protected@iwrite}{%
  \let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
  \patchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}%
  \def\efloat@iwrite#1{\expandafter\protected@iwrite\csname efloat@post#1\endcsname{}}%
}{}
% double 'unexpansion' now is needed
\appto{\appendix}{%
  \renewcommand{\thepostfigure}{S\arabic{postfigure}}%
  \setcounter{postfigure}{0}%
  \efloat@iwrite{fff}{%
    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{%
      \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}^^J%
      \setcounter{figure}{0}^^J%
    }}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

As we see in figure \ref{fig1} (and also in supplemental figure \ref{figS1}) \ldots

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{fig1}
\caption{One.} \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\clearpage % not necessary, just to make the figure go to the next page
\appendix

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{figS1}
\caption{Supplement, one.} \label{figS1}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @karlkoeller's answer above is simpler and seems to work fine; I added some of your explanation to it.  Thanks to both!!

Comment: @petrelharp I beg to differ. My solution doesn't require any strange code in the body of the document. If you want to restore the usual behavior, just comment out the patch to `\appendix`.

Comment: ah, I see!  yes, I agree.  I guess I called it simpler because it only used commands I already understood.

Comment: @egreg's code does not compile anymore. The first error is "Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }. \end{document}", but there are many more. I suspect that endfloat 2.6 introduced some breaking changes. Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please look at the non-answer above.

Comment: @mho87 Yes, there was a breaking change in `endfloat`, thanks for the input. I also took the occasion of filing a related bug report.